# PHP Mail Delayed Shared Hosting

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm developing a Drupal site on very generic shared LAMP hosting. My client insists on using the shared hosting company for some reason. (Is it OK to mention the hosting company?)

E-mails are sent via the standard MimeMail module, which is just the php `mail()` function.

I tried using without and then with their SMTP server.

Plain text mails are sent just fine, but HTML mails are either:

- Delayed by 20-45 minutes. Or
- being received as plaintext.

I see no errors in the Apache log. I have a PHP Mail log and it shows each mail as being sent instantly without error.

One other detail: HTML mails will send instantly IF there are no images. There is something about having an image (of any size) that their system -somehow- is blocking. And these are images in a public folder, basically just the company logo.

My question is: Is there any way for -me- to troubleshoot this? I call the hosting company and they literally say there is nothing they can do, except telling me to "reformat your e-mails to make them less 'spammy'. I can direct you to a web site for handy tips!" Which is ridiculous.

Is my next step to seek out another company to use for SMTP server?

Sorry if this is 'noob'... I just haven't run into a hosting company that literally -shrugs- off a problem like this and I don't know where to begin to troubleshoot.

```
From - Wed Mar 11 15:51:38 2015
X-Account-Key: account4
X-UIDL: 1426113840.449609.p3plgemini13-10.prod.phx.2013263616
X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
Received: (qmail 2803 invoked by uid 30297); 11 Mar 2015 22:44:00 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO p3plibsmtp02-02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net) ([68.178.213.2])
          (envelope-sender <mail@examplesite.us>)
          by p3plsmtp13-03.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (qmail-1.03) with SMTP
          for <mail@webdev.com>; 11 Mar 2015 22:44:00 -0000
Received: from qproxy2.mail.unifiedlayer.com ([69.89.16.161])
    by p3plibsmtp02-02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with bizsmtp
    id 2Njz1q01e3UWC0501Nk0e2; Wed, 11 Mar 2015 15:44:00 -0700
Received: (qmail 7585 invoked by uid 0); 11 Mar 2015 22:43:59 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO cmgw3) (10.0.90.84)
  by qproxy2.mail.unifiedlayer.com with SMTP; 11 Mar 2015 22:43:59 -0000
Received: from box1137.bluehost.com ([50.87.248.137])
    by cmgw3 with 
    id 2UPv1q00A2ycTAi01UPytd; Wed, 11 Mar 2015 22:23:58 -0600
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.1 cv=GJqbTI9K c=1 sm=1 tr=0
 a=Hf5REZnYO3k3U1JTpqXL+w==:117 a=Hf5REZnYO3k3U1JTpqXL+w==:17 a=cNaOj0WVAAAA:8
 a=f5113yIGAAAA:8 a=wPDyFdB5xvgA:10 a=MKtGQD3n3ToA:10 a=L9k2-N0lSLgA:10
 a=0jxqhgXFx10A:10 a=emO1SXQWCLwA:10 a=r77TgQKjGQsHNAKrUKIA:9
 a=9iDbn-4jx3cA:10 a=cKsnjEOsciEA:10 a=gZbpxnkM3yUA:10 a=Fr5XrKv2AAAA:8
 a=3Nchi1eACevrAwMXG-IA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=fF0D-C4TCVgA:10
 a=H2NqncWIT7EA:10 a=4dClL0zst7UA:10 a=NWVoK91CQyQA:10 a=39p1Jp6EAAAA:8
 a=SSmOFEACAAAA:8 a=o3d-oVfvMfNQkCSp:21 a=YhXZDRiokDvnJXKY:21
 a=mug9fxWn8JC3CvVH:21 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=RH5laGDJvsIA:10
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:51552 helo=box1137.bluehost.com)
    by box1137.bluehost.com with esmtp (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <mail@examplesite.us>)
    id 1YVp2i-0002B2-Sx
    for mail@webdev.com; Wed, 11 Mar 2015 16:23:56 -0600
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 16:23:54 -0600
To: mail@webdev.com
Subject: Order 993 at Example US
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1154:mimemail.module
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;
 boundary="2728078c5821b30553fe513fe5c265ca85961b121"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8Bit
X-Mailer:Drupal
Sender:"Example US" <mail@examplesite.us>
From: "Example US" <mail@examplesite.us>
X-Identified-User: {:box1137.bluehost.com:examplesite1:examplesite.us} {sentby:program running on server}
X-Nonspam: None
```

Comment: You decide what is okay to mention and what not. It should always comply with company policy, though :)

Comment: BTW, could you copy&paste the code you are using to send text and html mails?

Comment: End-user usage of shared web hosting is still off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry for being thick, but can you explain that? I'm not sure what it is that is off-topic? Mentioning the hosting company by name? I tried to avoid that but it seems like one needs the headers in order to troubleshoot. Can you suggest how I could edit to make this 'on-topic'?

Comment: You can't edit it to make it on topic. It's simply a scenario we do not support. Even if we could figure out what's going on, we could not provide an answer you could actually use. Whatever the issue is, the hosting provider (or _their_ provider) must fix it. Also, [sf] is _not_ a technical support website.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult, if not impossible to troubleshoot. Without access to their mail server logs you can only assume what's the issue.

Have you tried sending the email to different domains? Maybe it's the receiving end that causes the issues? Keep in mind that your mail reading application chooses how to display HTML mails.

> I just haven't run into a hosting company that literally -shrugs- off a problem like this

In my opinion, you should go and look for a different hosting company, then. Saying "there is nothing we can do" is not true, they just don't want to. Go and look for a company that is able to assist you if you have problems. They probably won't do it for free, but at least you get help.

Comment: I have tried sending e-mails to -many- domains and they all are delayed. It seems that any msg with an attachment or an image of any kind is delayed by that qproxy2.unifiedlayer.com hop. My boss -wants- to use this hosting company for some reason... she doesn't want to switch. I need some sort of 'ammunitition' to speak with the hosting company and get them to 'do something'.

Comment: Ammunition? What do you want to do? Shoot them? This is the wrong approach. You did everything in your power to trying to fix this. If she insists on staying on that company, it's her responsibility to tell you how you should proceed from this point onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the headers of the delayed email.  The `Received:` headers will show where you are being blocked.  It is likely the emails are being delayed by a spam/virus filter somewhere along the path.  The headers may indicate where the scanning is occurring as well as providing scan results.

Comment: I added the headers of a sample msg. I note that the 20 minute delay is added at the hop immediately after it gets past the bluehost box: qproxy2.mail.unifiedlayer.com  What is -that-?

Comment: @jchwebdev The delay on the first hop from your server.  Examine your Exim log, likely `/var/log/exim*/mainlog`.  You can used `exigrep` to retrieve the log messages for a single email.